# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11

Tags: c++, libraries, make

https://github.com/laazyboy13/linux-csgo-external/issues/6
How do I get it to find libx11-dev?

```
william@william-elementarylinux:~/csgohack$ make
Linking CXX executable build/csgo_external
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [build/csgo_external] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
william@william-elementarylinux:~/csgohack$ ld -lX11 --verbose
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   i386linux
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
   i386pep
   i386pe
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Script for -z combreloc: combine and sort reloc sections */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
          "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rela.dyn       :
    {
      *(.rela.init)
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rela.fini)
      *(.rela.rodata .rela.rodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rela.data .rela.data.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rela.tdata .rela.tdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rela.tbss .rela.tbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rela.ctors)
      *(.rela.dtors)
      *(.rela.got)
      *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      *(.rela.ldata .rela.ldata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.l.*)
      *(.rela.lbss .rela.lbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
      *(.rela.lrodata .rela.lrodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
      *(.rela.ifunc)
    }
  .rela.plt       :
    {
      *(.rela.plt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_start = .);
      *(.rela.iplt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_end = .);
    }
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) *(.iplt) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
  .eh_frame_hdr : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table
  .gcc_except_table.*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges
  .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) - ((CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - .) & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)); . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
  .tdata      : { *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*) }
  .tbss       : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.fini_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  .got            : { *(.got) *(.igot) }
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (SIZEOF (.got.plt) >= 24 ? 24 : 0, .);
  .got.plt        : { *(.got.plt)  *(.igot.plt) }
  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  _edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we don't
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  .lbss   :
  {
    *(.dynlbss)
    *(.lbss .lbss.* .gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
    *(LARGE_COMMON)
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  .lrodata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.lrodata .lrodata.* .gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
  }
  .ldata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.ldata .ldata.* .gnu.linkonce.l.*)
    . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}


==================================================
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libX11.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libX11.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libX11.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libX11.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so succeeded
-lX11 (//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so)
libxcb.so.1 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
found libxcb.so.1 at //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
libdl.so.2 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
found libdl.so.2 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
libc.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
found libc.so.6 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
libXau.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
found libXau.so.6 at //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6
libXdmcp.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
found libXdmcp.so.6 at //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

EDIT: 
I had a look at https://github.com/laazyboy13/linux-csgo-external/issues/5 and new error:

```
william@william-elementarylinux:~/csgohack$ sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386 libx11-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdrm-dev libexpat1-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libice-dev
  libjbig-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev liblzma-dev
  libpng12-dev libsm-dev libtiff5-dev libtiffxx5 libvpx-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev
  libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev
  libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev
  libxshmfence-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-fixes-dev
  x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libx11-dev libx11-dev:i386
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,256 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,020 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 215279 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libx11-dev_2%3a1.6.2-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-dev:amd64 (2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-dev:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../libx11-dev_2%3a1.6.2-1ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-dev:i386 (2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libx11-dev:amd64 (2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libx11-dev:i386 (2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2) ...
william@william-elementarylinux:~/csgohack$ make
Linking CXX executable build/csgo_external
CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x337): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
main.cpp:(.text+0x37f): undefined reference to `XKeysymToKeycode'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3bb): undefined reference to `XGrabKey'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3d4): undefined reference to `XSelectInput'
main.cpp:(.text+0xc7a): undefined reference to `XNextEvent'
main.cpp:(.text+0xcca): undefined reference to `XUngrabKey'
main.cpp:(.text+0xd03): undefined reference to `XGrabKey'
main.cpp:(.text+0xd1c): undefined reference to `XSelectInput'
main.cpp:(.text+0xd2d): undefined reference to `XPending'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [build/csgo_external] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

EDIT2:

```
$ apt-cache policy libx11-dev
libx11-dev:
  Installed: 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so | grep -P '^XOpenDisplay'
XOpenDisplay
```

EDIT3: I followed @xiaodongjie's answer's steps and the CMakeLists.txt file. I used github.com/laazyboy13/linux-csgo-external from the 15th commit. I edited the linux-csgo-external-master/CMakeLists.txt file to

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(csgo_external)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m32 -std=c++11")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ./build)

set(SOURCE_FILES log.cpp remote.cpp netvar.cpp hack.cpp main.cpp)
add_executable(csgo_external ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(csgo_external "-lX11")
```

and ran `cmake .` and `make`

This is the log:

```
william@william-elementarylinux:~$ cd ~/linux-csgo-external-master/
william@william-elementarylinux:~/linux-csgo-external-master$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/william/linux-csgo-external-master
william@william-elementarylinux:~/linux-csgo-external-master$ make
Scanning dependencies of target csgo_external
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/log.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/remote.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/netvar.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/hack.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable build/csgo_external
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [build/csgo_external] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
william@william-elementarylinux:~/linux-csgo-external-master$
```

EDIT4: Solved using xiaodongjie's steps and re-installing `libx11-dev:i386` as well.

Comment: I don't understand. Where is the `csgohack` repository on GitHub? You have posted an issue on https://github.com/laazyboy13/linux-csgo-external but this is not the source repository for `csgohack`.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libx11-dev; strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so | grep -P '^XOpenDisplay'`

Comment: I just changed the file name. Edited. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @gogobebe2 please read my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to build it, too.

So I got same error. I found the reason why this error is occurred.

`-lX11` is not `cflag`(`compile flag`), it's a link flag.
So this flag needs to be in `link flags` rather than `cflags`.
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html

Above page describe about how to set link flags.
So I modified the CMakeLists.txt as follow.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(csgo_external)

#removed -lX11 from following line.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m32 -std=c++11")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ./build)

set(SOURCE_FILES log.cpp remote.cpp netvar.cpp hack.cpp main.cpp)
add_executable(csgo_external ${SOURCE_FILES})
#appended following line.
target_link_libraries(csgo_external "-lX11")
```

Also, make sure you have `libx11-dev:i386` as well as `libx11-dev`

Comment: Ok, I used https://github.com/laazyboy13/linux-csgo-external from the 15th commit. I edited the linux-csgo-external-master/CMakeLists.txt file to `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(csgo_external)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m32 -std=c++11")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ./build)

set(SOURCE_FILES log.cpp remote.cpp netvar.cpp hack.cpp main.cpp)
add_executable(csgo_external ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(csgo_external "-lX11")` and ran `cmake .` and `make` This is the log: EDIT3 in my question.

Comment: OHHH IT FINALLY WORKEDD!!!! I re-installed `libx11-dev:i386` in combination with your fix and it worked! Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm very happy with this answer if it helps you and AU users who have same problems.

Comment: Thanks so much. I can't thank you enough xiaodongjie!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: The file `CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/link.txt` is created by the command `cmake .`. Once this file has been changed, run the command `cmake` not again, otherwise your changes will be overwritten. The real problem is in `CMakeLists.txt`. Therefore, the note at the end of the answer.

---

The problem is in `CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/link.txt` after running `cmake`. `-lX11` must come after

```
[…] CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/main.cpp.o
```

or at the end.

Edit the file `CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/link.txt`

```
nano CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/link.txt
```

and replace

```
/usr/bin/c++ -m32 -std=c++11 -lX11 CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/log.cpp.o CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/remote.cpp.o CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/netvar.cpp.o CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/hack.cpp.o CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/main.cpp.o  -o build/csgo_external -rdynamic
```

with

```
/usr/bin/c++ -m32 -std=c++11 CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/log.cpp.o CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/remote.cpp.o CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/netvar.cpp.o CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/hack.cpp.o CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/main.cpp.o  -o build/csgo_external -rdynamic -lX11
```

After that, contact the developer. They have to change something in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: I just tested it and it still didn't work. Same error message.  :(

Comment: I have it also tested. Sorry. :\

Comment: Perhaps there is an additional file with the same problem.

Comment: Have you tested the file after running `cmake`?

Comment: Works perfect, but after changing `CMakeFiles/csgo_external.dir/link.txt`, don't run `cmake` again.

Comment: Yeah. Apparently other people dont have the same problem as me so it could be me not their code.

Comment: I believe, it's a compiler thing only on Linux.

Comment: Well this csgo external is only for Linux and other people who use Linux don't have the problem.